# Network availability check in tizen wearable with html

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

Using HTML and javascript, is there any way to check if the network is available in Samsung gear s2?

Comment: Hello, do you want to check internet connectivity ?

Comment: Yes.  I tried using this code. But it didnt work for me. $(document).on('online', function (event) {}. And in android native code we can check this easily. Tizen native code is also providing ways to check this. But with javascript or jquery can we check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check internet connection status, try like this

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no">
    <title>Circular UI</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/tau/wearable/theme/default/tau.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (-tizen-geometric-shape: circle)" href="lib/tau/wearable/theme/default/tau.circle.min.css">
    <!-- load theme file for your application -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ui-page ui-page-active" id="main">
        <header class="ui-header">
            <h2 class="ui-title">Basic</h2>
        </header>
        <div class="ui-content content-padding">
            <ul class="ui-listview">
                <p id="connectionStatus">N/A</p>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/tau/wearable/js/tau.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/circle-helper.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="lowBatteryCheck.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
( function () {

    var isOnline = navigator.onLine;
    var con = document.getElementById("connectionStatus");

    if(isOnline){
        con.innerHTML = "Connection is available";
        console.log("Connection is available");
    }else{
        con.innerHTML = "Connection is not available";
        console.log("Connection is not available");
    }


    window.addEventListener( 'tizenhwkey', function( ev ) {
        if( ev.keyName === "back" ) {
            var page = document.getElementsByClassName( 'ui-page-active' )[0],
                pageid = page ? page.id : "";
            if( pageid === "main" ) {
                try {
                    tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().exit();
                } catch (ignore) {
                }
            } else {
                window.history.back();
            }
        }
    } );
} () );
```

> Don't forget to add these in config file. 
>   **config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns:tizen="http://tizen.org/ns/widgets" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" id="http://yourdomain/ConnectionCheck" version="1.0.0" viewmodes="maximized">
    <tizen:application id="6NMriwCsz0.ConnectionCheck" package="6NMriwCsz0" required_version="2.3.1"/>
    <content src="index.html"/>
    <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/screen.size.normal"/>
    <icon src="icon.png"/>
    <name>ConnectionCheck</name>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/application.launch"/>
    <tizen:profile name="wearable"/>
    <tizen:setting hwkey-event="enable"/>
</widget>
```

> I just check this. It works fine for me. You can also check [this](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/forums/web-application-development/how-internet-connection-status-should-display-user.#answer-comment).

If you want to check only wifi status,

```
wifiData.signalStrength // provide the signal strength
wifiData.status // return ON or OFF to get the wifi status
```

Check [this](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/sample/web/Communication/WiFi_Info/js/app.js?langredirect=1)

Comment: Thanks.. I'll try this

Comment: I tried in emulator. It worked great.. But couldn't check in device. So I didnt update. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Which device are you using ?

Comment: Samsung gear s2. I've some network connectivity issues. So i couldnt check in device.